# sleeping a new thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

so im trying to delay the sending of email from my program.
In order to keep the UI interactive, i started a new thread and called the email method in the thread. It works. It sends the emails. However i cant figure out how to sleep the thread.
Ive tried using Thread.sleep() in the actual email method, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(recipientAddress, subjectLine, finalbody); }));
                oThread.Start();
```

email method..

```
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(string recipient, string subject, string body)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);

        try
        {

            // Create the Outlook application.
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            // Set HTMLBody. 
            //add the body of the email
            oMsg.Body = body;

            oMsg.Subject = subject;
            // Add a recipient.
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
            // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
            oRecip.Resolve();
            // Send.
            oMsg.Send();
            // Clean up.
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;



        }//end of try block
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }//end of catch

        //end of Email Method
    }
```

Comment: maybe this is a silly question, but why do you want the thread to sleep?

Comment: Have you looked into using a Timer?

Comment: Step through it in a debugger. You can find this problem yourself, I guess. It is an important skill to learn.

Comment: is there a reason you´re sending the mail via outlook?

Comment: yes..the server will filter the mail out if its not sent using outlook exchange and what not...have to send the mail using my school email adresss. I havent really looked into sending it another way.

Comment: i need the emails to be sent around a 1 minute interval or else the server acts up

Comment: In that case you should add your mail information to a list and having a thread to look at it once a minute (have a look at ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject

Comment: so I guess you are storing email objects in a to-be-sent list and then after 1 minute you are sending them? I guess you could just have a timer that checks if you have anything to send every minute. It's a bit simpler than a thread and handles the timing problem.

Comment: ok ill look into using a timer...dont be surprised if you see a question posted about timers soon...im pretty new to programming, i try and google for info before asking a question but sometimes its hard to figure out what to do on my own.

Comment: as a side note, make a finally block and put all your foo = null's there (should you be calling a .close() method on any of these?) then it's if (foo != null) foo.close()

Comment: On writing questions: before posting please see if you have "doesnt seem to work" or "does not work" or "simply fails" in the post and replace with actual failure+message+expected behavior. It will make question much more actionable.

Comment: Do you set your Thread as Background? Make sure your Thread is different of main thread. my suggestion is that use BackgroundWorker instead of Thread.

Comment: ok ill look up some info on background worker

Comment: I have never, ever, know Sleep() calls to not work.  How simple an API call can you get?  Where is the while(true) loop and input queue?  What's the point of waiting 60000 if you're not going to loop round again and check some queue for more email requests?

Comment: well sleep works fine, it just sleeps the main thread. What i need is to sleep the new thread. but i cant. the method sleep doesnt exist for that new thread, suspend() does though.

Comment: it is work in my code. your question is my answer! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing apparently wrong with the code you've posted. However, thread.Suspend() is a very old API = it has been deprecated/obsoleted since .NET 2.0, as it's not safe to do this.

The static method Thread.Sleep(N) most certainly suspends the calling thread for N milliseconds.

To clarify; calling Thread.Sleep suspends the **calling thread**, so in your example code, where you have;

```
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(string recipient, string subject, string body)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    ...
}
```

The call to Thread.Sleep(60000) is suspending the thread which is executing the method sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK. And since you appear to be calling that method in it's own thread,as evidenced by;

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(recipientAddress, subjectLine, finalbody); }));
oThread.Start();
```

the correct thread should be suspended.

There is no way to do something like this;

```
 Thread t = new Thread();
 t.Start();
 t.Sleep(60000);
```

You can start, or kill a running thread, but not sleep/suspend it. As noted - this API was deprecated as it is not a safe way to implement thread synchronisation (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for an  explanation of why this is not a good idea).

Comment: im using visual studio 2012. and I can use Thread.Sleep(), but what i really need to do is oThread.sleep. oThread is the thread i used to send the emails, the first line of code

Comment: yeah. I mean looking at the code, putting thread.sleep in the method that sends the emails sleeps the current thread. and since I call that method in the new thread...i would think it would sleep it for 1 minute...but the emails dont send at all. Im puzzled

Comment: Emails not sending != thread not sleeping. Put a breakpoint on the line that sleeps the thread, and one on the subsequent line. Then you can get a fair idea that the thread is sleeping for 60s. Once you've confirmed that, you can move on to working out why the emails aren't sending.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a bit new to programming I won't try to explain all the relevant details but I thought it was cool that you showed me a new trick with your sample so I wanted to help you out if I could.

This isn't the *only* way to code this but I can tell you this is a reasonable one.  It uses a background worker component to keep the UI responsive while sending the email.  Note the use of the background worker's provided events DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted.  The setup for these events took place in the designer which is why I [zipped the solution up for you](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B906O1xOpCtBa0JhdUwzTGR0cjA) so you could take a look at the whole thing (I did so with google Drive and this is my first attempt doing a public share - if the link opens for you like it does for me, you'll get a File menu from which you can select Download).

I created an inner private class and passed it to the background worker.  I do this because I don't want to access the data in my UI components from code running in a different thread.  This will not always cause a problem but I find it to be a good practice in general.  Also, it makes it so if I want to refactor the code later it will be easier to take the lines from DoWork and put them somewhere else without any fuss.

On the more general area of multi threaded programming - it's a multi faceted subject and you don't need to get it all right away.  [This](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) is my favorite tutorial (the book is great too).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace Emailer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.sendEmailBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new _Email
            {
                Recipient = this.recipientTextBox.Text,
                Subject = this.subjectTextBox.Text,
                Body = this.emailToSendTextBox.Text
            });
        }

        private class _Email
        {
            public string Body { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Recipient { get; set; }
        }

        private void sendEmailBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var email = (_Email)e.Argument;

            try
            {
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                oMsg.Body = email.Body;
                oMsg.Subject = email.Subject;
                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(email.Recipient);
                oRecip.Resolve();
                oMsg.Send();
                oRecip = null;
                oRecips = null;
                oMsg = null;
                oApp = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.Result = ex;
            }

            e.Result = true;
        }

        private void sendEmailBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message;

            if (e.Result is Exception) 
                message = "Error sending email: " + (e.Result as Exception).Message;
            else if (e.Result is bool && (bool)e.Result)
                message = "Email is sent";
            else 
                throw new Exception("Internal Error: not expecting " + e.Result.GetType().FullName);

            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }
}
```